# Как вывести историю перехода только по каталогам в Linux командой grep?

Tags: linux, debian, grep, history

Необходимо вывести историю перехода по cd, но только чтобы показывало папки, а не все подряд команды.

Comment: `fc -nl -10000 | grep -e "^\s*\(cd\|pushd\|popd\) "`.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: добрый день, а с помощью команды history | grep можно это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

А чё так сложно-то, вот так же проще

history | grep cd

Comment: да уж, какой вопрос, такой и ответ, одного уровня.